# Why is this happening with faces?

Tags: modeling, rendering, vertices, edges

Would it be possible to you to explain how and why this happens? (I am noob (sorry)

[image: Sword blade (Edit Mod)]

[image: Render View]

Comment: I'm guessing that you're referring to the triangles that appear to the right in the render, but you really should include a little more text that describes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quads are not planar. But you have most probably flat shading. And so you will see the shading for the two underlying tris of this quad therefore.

Try to activate Auto Smooth, and give it a angle of let's say 5. Increase or decrease the value to your needs. Auto Smooth can be found in the Properties editor in the Data tab.

[image]